# How to clear the turtle position, rotation and anyother thing made already. (Turtle is embedded inside a tkinter window)

Tags: python, tkinter, turtle-graphics

I was trying to create a program inside tkinter that draws different patterns based on user input. I want a 'clear' button on my window that can clear everything on the window. I tried 'turtle.clear" and 'turtle.reset', they work but they open a new turtle window which I dont want and also that I am using `tut = turtle.RawTurtle()`. What can I do to try to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I use the following sample code:

```py
    from tkinter import *
    from turtle import *

    root = Tk()

    tut = None

    def reset_button():
       tut.reset()
       tut.hideturtle()

    def draw_again():
       tut.speed('fastest')
       tut.color('blue', 'yellow')
       tut.begin_fill()
       while True:
          tut.forward(200)
          tut.left(170)
          if abs(tut.pos()) < 1:
             break
       tut.end_fill()

    button1 = Button(text = 'Reset', command = reset_button)
    button1.pack()

    button2 = Button(text = 'Draw', command = draw_again)
    button2.pack()

    canvas_Main = Canvas(root, bg='#ffffff', width = 500, height = 500)
    canvas_Main.pack()

    tut = RawTurtle(canvas_Main)

    tut.speed('fastest')
    tut.color('red', 'yellow')
    tut.begin_fill()
    while True:
       tut.forward(200)
       tut.left(170)
          if abs(tut.pos()) < 1:
             break
    tut.end_fill()

    root.mainloop()
```